# Authorization denial using Fusion Table API

Tags: java, google-fusion-tables

My Code :

```
public class restletexample {

    String URI = "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/fusiontables/v1/tables/tableid/import";

    HashMap<String, String> urlVariables = new HashMap<String, String>();

    String column = "'Moth', '30', '2012','efef','efefef'";

    public void testrestlet() {

        urlVariables.put("key=", "KEY");

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        restTemplate.postForLocation(URI, column, urlVariables);

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        restletexample rst = new restletexample();
        rst.testrestlet();

    }

}
```

Exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 401 Unauthorized
```

I have generated key in the API console and am using the same . I donot know why google is not authorizing my request .Need help ...breaking my head since last 4 hours .

Answer (score 1):

Your URI seems wrong-  "tableid" should be replaced with the actual ID of your table.

Comment: I didnot want to make my tableid public that why i didnot write that .